# Mac Pro Dual Displays

Tags: macos, hardware, display, graphics

I have a 2007 Mac Pro that shipped with 10.4.7, and an ATI Radeon X1900 XT graphics card. The card has two DVI outputs for a dual display setup.

I recently updated my OSX to Snow Leopard and have never tried to connect a second monitor.

Now, when I try to connect a second monitor, OSX does not detect it. Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your main screen in the slot that does not work. If you still get no video i think the port on the video card is dead.

What size screens are you using though?